# Android- I have 5 switch widget in android I want to use each one of the switch and their combination to show the result

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I am having a problem with writing cases for each switch(whether it is on or off) using if-else condition. For example, there are three switches(widget) in android one simple case is only one switch is working at a time, another case is in a pair like 1 and 2 working or 2 and 3 working or 1 and 3 working or all three working together on the basis of that wanna show the results which are the switches on/working at a time. So using if-else condition method for 8 or more switches is an impossible task. So I want to know some efficient and good method of making such conditions possible.

Answer (score 0):

If you look closely, those switches will resemble words in binary format. Following your eight switches example, let's say `10010101` represent the disposition of those, where the switch `0` is on, `1` is off and so on.

Make each switch affect one bit in an Integer, being `0` off and `1` on for example and you can use that very number in a switch construct to handle each case.

Comment: It means I have to use the "for" loop method for n switches to check which are the switch are on and by getting that information I have to implement the working of that switches together.

Comment: Thank you Eddiel it saved my lot of time.